# the code gives me the wrong output in bell triangle (assembly language emu8086)

Tags: assembly, emulation, x86-16

i want to make bell triangle with the assembly language emu8086
[like this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_triangle#CITEREFGardner1978)

i have problem in this line

```
mov ch,a[DI-(1+d)]
```

d=1 ;variable increment 
I tried to remove (1+d) and put it 2 to be like this

```
mov ch,a[DI-2]
```

it gives me the result that i want but i want to use the variable (d) cause it changes every time

thats where the problem is

```
J2:
cmp DI,bx
JE J1
mov al, a[DI] 
mov ch,a[DI-(1+d)] //in this line//
add al,ch
inc di
mov a[DI],al
print ' '
call print_num 
mov dl,c 
mov b,dx
jmp J2
```

thats the output

```
1
1 2
2 2 2
2 2 2 2
```

but it should be like this

```
1
1 2
2 3 5 
5 7 10 15
```

i think the problem is the brackets

Comment: What is `d` declares as?

Comment: 'd' it is A variable increase by 1 in the loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only have varying address components in processor registers.

```
mov ch,a[DI-(1+d)]
```

Assuming **d** is a word sized variable I suggest you code :

```
push bx  ;Save because you use it elsewhere!
mov bx,d
neg bx
mov ch,a[DI-1+BX]
pop bx
```